# Can one extend the norm function to the symmetric square of a (complexified) Clifford algebra?

Tags: norms, clifford-algebras

Let $A = Cl_{r,s} \otimes \mathbb{C}$ be the complexification of the real Clifford algebra $Cl_{r,s}$ associated to a non-degenerate quadratic form on $\mathbb{R}^n$, with $n = r+s$, with signature $(r,s)$ ($r$ pluses and $s$ minuses).

Note that an element $x \in Cl_{r,s}$ is invertible iff its norm $N(x)$ is nonzero. I think it is probably straightforward to define an appropriate norm function on the complexification $A$ such that $x \in A$ is invertible iff its norm $N(x)$ is nonzero.

My question is related to the symmetric square $A \odot A$ over $\mathbb{C}$. One may define the following product on $A \odot A$, inherited from the product in $A$:

$$(a_1 \odot a_2).(a_3 \odot a_4) = (a_1.a_3) \odot (a_2.a_4) + (a_1.a_4) \odot (a_2.a_3),$$

extended to $A \odot A$ by imposing bilinearity of the product.

Is there a way to define a norm function on $A \odot A$? More specifically, can one define a multiplicative function from $A \odot A$ to $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$? The main property I would like this norm function $N$ to have is that $x \in A \odot A$ is invertible iff $N(x)$ is nonzero. So given an element $x \in A \odot A$, it would allow us to determine whether or not it is invertible, by simply computing its norm.